# How do we make sense of 'Now there were dwelling in Jerusalem God-fearing Jews from every nation under heaven' in Acts 2:5?

Tags: acts

Acts 2:5 says

> "Now there were dwelling in Jerusalem God-fearing Jews from every
> nation under heaven."

The straightforward English reading of this makes it sound false - there were no Jews from North America or South America at Jerusalem, despite those places having nations at the time. Can the sentence construction support a different sense, is it just figurative language, or is there another way to make sense of it without it being false?

Comment: You will need to supply documented evidence of 1) the existence, in the first century, of 'nations' (not just scattered tribes or individuals) in the American continents and 2) that there were no Jews among them and 3) that these Jews were not in Jerusalem at the time spoken of. I think you need to support your research on this question with cited references.

Comment: @NigelJ Pretty certain the onus of proof is on you for these! 1. Explain away the anthropological evidence that nations existed in the Americas around this time. 2. Give any evidence that Jews existed among these ('non-existent'?) nations. 3. Show how they got from the Americas to Jerusalem when there is no known plausible way this could have happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acts 2:5

> "Now there were dwelling in Jerusalem **God-fearing Jews** from every nation under heaven."

One can interpret this verse as hyperbole.

It is also possible to interpret this verse literally:
At that time, there were probably no God-fearing Jews living in the Americas. So none of them showed up in Jerusalem.

A more balanced approach is to interpret it idiomatically, meaning every nation where the Jews were dispersed. The context lists the nations:

> 5 Now there were staying in Jerusalem God-fearing Jews from every nation under heaven. 6When they heard this sound, a crowd came together in bewilderment, because each one heard their own language being spoken. 7Utterly amazed, they asked: “Aren’t all these who are speaking Galileans? 8Then how is it that each of us hears them in our native language? 9Parthians, Medes and Elamites; residents of Mesopotamia, Judea and Cappadocia, Pontus and Asia,  10Phrygia and Pamphylia, Egypt and the parts of Libya near Cyrene; visitors from Rome 11(both Jews and converts to Judaism); Cretans and Arabs—we hear them declaring the wonders of God in our own tongues!”

How do we make sense of 'Now there were dwelling in Jerusalem God-fearing Jews from every nation under heaven' in Acts 2:5?

There are 3 ways to make sense of it: hyperbole, literal, or idiom. I think the last one is most reasonable.